# ngx-select-dropdown patch value with id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following problem when using ngx select.
I have the following object, employe = {id: 20, name: "Company 1", "status": "enabled"}.
Always select in the options to show the name and when I go back I send the id. But when I get this value, the ngx select gets lost and cannot make the binding and get the company name.
Using the normal html select is working ok. I'll leave the two examples below.

```
<ngx-select-dropdown [config]="employeConfig" [options]="employe" name="employe" [(ngModel)]="employe" required>
</ngx-select-dropdown>
  employeConfig= {
    displayKey: 'name',
    search: true,
    height: 'auto',
    placeholder: 'Select a position',
    limitTo: this._cargos.length,
    moreText: 'item',
    noResultsFound: 'No results found',
    searchPlaceholder: 'Search',
    searchOnKey: 'name',
  };

<select required [(ngModel)]="employe" (click)="verifyVaga()" name="employe">
          <option *ngFor="let candidate of candidates" [value]="candidate.id"> {{employe.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you format the code? For better readability. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [ngx-select-dropdown documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-select-dropdown), `[options]` requires Array value. While you pass `employe` which is an object to `[options]`.

```
[options]="employe"
```

You need to pass `candidates` to `[options]`.

```
<ngx-select-dropdown
  [config]="employeConfig"
  [options]="candidates"
  name="employe"
  [(ngModel)]="employe"
  required
>
</ngx-select-dropdown>
```

**Updated:**

From *ngx-select-dropdown* library and demo, it seems to return selected object when `[options]`'s value is an array of objects. And it doesn't support to specify id as return selected value just like `displayKey` configuration.

To get selected id only:

```js
let selectedId = this.employe.id;
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vf4znk?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: But as I said above, the backend doesn't return the complete object, just the id.
I edited the stack for you to check
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7ow516?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Okay sorry about that. `ngx-select-dropdown` library look like cannot specify id as `displayKey` in config. If you want to get the selected id, you should use `this.employe.id`.

Comment: As well? could you do it on stackblitz please?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vf4znk?file=src/app/app.component.html